# JavaScript concatenation, many things being loaded that is not needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are third party solutions to loading js files that are needed, such as requirejs, but in my project I won't be able to.

I have the following design pattern for many of my scripts, which are now being loaded on the appropriate pages using the backend framework, Magento. However, I was going to concatenate all of the scripts into one file, which has me wondering what the costs are with having all those events being loaded with elements that do not exist:

```
var Forms = (function($){
    var Forms = function(){
        var context = this;
        $(function(){
            //Jquery Validate for newsletter form
            context.newsletter_validate_detail = $( "#newsletter-validate-detail" ).validate({
                errorClass: 'form-error',
                errorElement: 'div',
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email:true
                    },
                    gender: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    'required': {
                        required: true
                    }

                },
                messages: {
                    gender: "Please select something"
                }
            });
        });
    };

    Forms.prototype.getForm = function(id){
        return this[id];
    };

    return Forms;
})(jQuery);

var test = new Forms();
```

For example, if I have all my scripts concatenated then all of the `$(function(){})` will be executed even if its content won't exist in the DOM. Surely, that will result in some performance hit?

Is the correct way of handling this to have a `<script> var f = new Forms(); </script>` in the actual template files that need it?

NOTE: I am not able to use 3rd party solutions like requirejs

Comment: `var Forms = new Forms();` best JS line I've seen in a while :)

Comment: "I was going to concatenate all of the scripts into one file" Don't include scripts that are not required on that page. Is that simple. Why would you download extra bytes? Is this a single page application?

Comment: haha I totally just wrote that down quickly for the example. lol

Comment: I am wondering, do browsers keep cache of script documents? I think they do. Maybe that's a pro to this idea?

Comment: Yes I guess thats the whole point to combine the site's js files into one. Do it all on the first load. But you'll have jquery scanning the Dom for things that do not exist...

Comment: That's why jQuery UI (for example) has its widget architecture, where elements are enhanced into widgets when they come in existence, not when the load event occurs. Binding your logic to the load event only makes sense when your DOM is complete at that time.

Comment: On the other hand, have you *measured* it? Is it measurably slow to have jQuery search for a few non-existent elements at page load? Something like `$("#newsletter-validate-detail")` is very fast. Don't optimize based on gut feelings.